# ¿como ejecutar el metodo PUT en django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, djangorestframework

estoy tratando de contruir una api donde ejecuto el metodo put. el tema es que me toca trabajar con formularios, y no encuentro informacion acerca de como ejecutar el metodo PUT en el view junto con formulario

```
if request.method == "PUT":
    companies = list(Company.objects.filter(id=id).values())
    form = CompanyForm(request.PUT) 
    if form.is_valid():
        if len(companies) > 0:
            company = Company.objects.get(id=id)
            company.name = form.name
            company.fundation = form.fundation
            company.web_site = form.web_site
            company.save()

            datos = {"messege": "success"}
        else:
            datos = {"messege": "company not found..."}
# 
    return JsonResponse(datos)

else:
    form = CompanyForm()

return render(request, './api/company_put_form.html', {'form':form})
```

eso es lo que llevo, usé la logica de el metodo post que tengo pero cambiando con datos de la progamacion orientada a objetos.

enserio necesito ayuda.

Comment: django no cuenta con el metodo put.... aunque igual solo existen get y post mientras que put y delete son inputs con dicho name!

Comment: gracias y como puedo invocarlos?

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien tu pregunta, pero para crear APIs te aconsejo usar [ninja-api](https://django-ninja.rest-framework.com/). Para el caso que tú estás tratando sería algo como esto:

```py
@api.post("/companies")
 
def companies(request, companies: str = Form(...), name: str = Form(...)):

return {'companies': companies', name': name}
```

Creo que deberías ordenar más tu lógica para saber qué es lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: gracias, lo que trato de hacer es uso del metodo put, para actualizar datos